# Content type when accept header is empty or unknown jax-rs

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

What is the default content returned when accept header is empty?

The below code returns application/xml when accept header is empty which maps to findAll(). Is there a way to force jax-rs to execute findAllAtom() when accept header is empty or unknown.
I am using restEasy version 2 with Jboss Application server and Adbera 1.1.2

```
@Stateless
@Path("quotes")
public class QuoteFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Quote> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "RestFullDayTraderPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public QuoteFacadeREST() {
        super(Quote.class);
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<Quote> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({"application/atom+xml"})
    @GET
    public Feed findAllAtom() throws Exception {
        Factory factory = abdera.getFactory();
        Feed feed = abdera.getFactory().newFeed();
        feed.setId("tag:example.org,2007:/foo");
        feed.setTitle("Feed Title");
        feed.setSubtitle("Feed subtitle");
        feed.setUpdated(new Date());
        feed.addAuthor("My Name");
        feed.addLink("http://example.com");
        feed.addLink("http://example.com","self");
        Entry entry = feed.addEntry();
        entry.setId("tag:example.org,2007:/foo/entries/2");
        entry.setTitle("Entry title 22 44");
        entry.setUpdated(new Date());
        entry.setPublished(new Date());
        entry.setSummary("Feed Summary");
        entry.setContent("One line content");
        return feed;
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request without Accept header means that client expects anything, like if it has specified `*/*`. Basically if you have two methods that differ only by `@Produces` and Accept header means "any", there is no way for a JAX-RS framework how to choose the method, so according to spec it chooses the first one (See JSR-311 3.7.2)

I believe that the best solution will be sending Accept header with an exact type.
Otherwise you can differ methods by different URLs: add  `@Path("/xml")` and  `@Path("/atom")` to the methods.

Comment: in my test cases I am using rssOwl as a rest client. rssOwl is sending an empty accept header. This might be the situation with few other ATOM clients. One way to handle this is to use url based content negotiation but I prefer to use header hence the above question.

Comment: You cannot do it with pure JAX-RS. With Apache Wink support content type shortcuts. The shortcuts are passed as query param in url, so calling ATOM will be http://host:port/app?alt=atom. See http://incubator.apache.org/wink/1.1/html/5.1%20Registration%20and%20Configuration.html

Comment: i will accept your previous suggestion. I am going to implement url based content negotiation, at-least for the main feeds.